# Where are the keyframes for the textures tab in the Properties

Tags: keyframes, properties, graph-editor, timeline, dopesheet

I am using this texture in **Compositing**

I have tried to find they keyframe for this :

[image: texture properties, with a position of color ramp keyframed]

But have not been able to find it

[image: Dope Sheet]

I turned off **Only Show Selected** and turned on **Show Hidden** but it's not there, I have even tried searching but nothing came up.

Is there a way that I can be able to see it?

Comment: What does it give if you select the Texture node in the Compositor window? https://zupimages.net/up/23/13/pcps.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you can see it, if you use it e.g. on a cube -> displacement modifier and if you select the cube. If this doesn't work, pls provide blend file to check out.

Comment: Forgot to specify that I'm using it in **Compositing**

Comment: @BeeAPotato Unfortunately this seems to be the only way to manipulate the keyframes in the _Dope Sheet_ and also the _Graph Editor_. You can disable the _Displacement_ modifier if you don't want to displace the mesh, but at least you can modifiy the keyframes then. Although keyframed animations in the _Compositor_ do show up in the _Dope Sheet_ under _Compositing Nodetree_, this only shows keyframes that are set in the _Compositor_ itself - but the texture is only referenced in there, it is not keyframed within the _Compositor_ (unless you set keyframes for the _Offset_ or _Scale_ values).